# MVC LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method call function - when to call function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to call a function during the LINQ statement which obviously can't be translated to SQL.  Here is my code, I am trying to convert a datetime to number of weeks.  What is the best approach, do I loop through the data after and update the ViewModel?

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Listings(string categoryName)
{
    HomeServices service = new HomeServices();

    return View(service.GetListingsViewModel(categoryName);
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class ResultsViewModel
{
    public System.Guid AdGuid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ListDate { get; set; }
    public string ListingAge { get; set; }
    public string Image1 { get; set; }

}
public class ListingsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ResultsViewModel> ResultsVM { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

**Services**

```
internal ListingsViewModel GetListingsViewModel(string categoryName)
{
    var listings = GetListingsVM(categoryName);
    var totalCount = listings.Count();

    return new ListingsViewModel()
    {
        ListingResultsVM = listings,
        TotalCount = totalCount
    };
}

internal IEnumerable<ResultsViewModel> GetListingsVM(string categoryName)
{
    var listings = Listings
      .Where(x => x.Category == categoryName)
      .Select(x => new ResultsViewModel
    {
        AdGuid = x.AdGuid,
        ListDate = x.ListDate,
        ListingAge = Logic.App.GetListingAge(x.BirthDate ?? DateTime.Now),
        Image1 = x.ListingImage.Image1
    });

    return listings;
}
```

**Logic.App**

```
public static string GetListingAge(System.DateTime varListDate)
{
    //Function code to convert DateTime to Weeks
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Download required data. Then, Locally manipulate it into requirements.

```
var listings = Listings
  .Where(x => x.Category == categoryName)
  .Select(x => new 
  {
    AdGuid = x.AdGuid,
    ListDate = x.ListDate,
    Image1 = x.ListingImage.Image1
  })
  .AsEnumerable() // make call to DB
  .Select(x => new ResultsViewModel
  {
    AdGuid = x.AdGuid,
    ListDate = x.ListDate,
    ListingAge = Logic.App.GetListingAge(x.BirthDate ?? DateTime.Now),
    Image1 = x.Image1
  })
  .ToList();  //Materialize the local query into a real list.
```

I highly recommend you always `.ToList()` at the end of these calls.  Other wise multiple calls to this method will return *literally different* list of `ResultsViewModel`.

[What can happen if you return an IQueryable as an IEnumerable](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xB98QS).

Comment: Can the .Count() be executed after it has been converted to .ToList(), since it won't be making another SQL call?

Comment: Why wouldn't the model property be `public int TotalCount { get { return ResultsVM.Count(); } }`?  Encapsulating the logic keeps the propery logic [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Sorry, this was incomplete code.  I have paging built in and need to return a totalCount of all records while only returning a subset based on the current page.

Comment: That's a completely *different* question.  It has been asked and answer many many times on SO already.  Since the number of records is completely independant of resolving a model, I'd make that a separate method.  Making a call for Count is super optimized, do it by itself.

Comment: The answer to the not so completely _different_ question is **yes**, you can perform a .Count() after the above code executes.

Comment: @BrianSalta I believe he wants the *total count before a where clause*, in which case, just `Listings.Count()` is `sql` optimal.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to call a method that obviously can't be called in SQL.

Are you sure? With the latest version of SQL you can tell EF to call a User Defined Function in the database instead of calling a C# function call.

You want to annotate the function with `DbFunction`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `GetListingAge()` doesn't exist in SQL server.  It's certainly possible to replicate it.

Comment: You can either create a UDF as I said or use .net in SQL server to implement it.